# Problems verifying signatures created with python RSA in phpseclib

Tags: php, python, phpseclib

I have a php page that recieves a POST request that includes some data and the signature so I can verify it, it is signed using SHA256 and RSA, now when I try to verify the signature using phpseclib, it fails, however if I sign the same exact message using `phpseclib` and try it in php the signature verifies alright.

This is my phpcode

```
$rsa->loadKey($publicKey);
$rsa->setSignatureMode(CRYPT_RSA_SIGNATURE_PKCS1);
$rsa->setHash('sha256');
$signature = $headers['authorization'];

echo $rsa->verify($canonical,base64_decode($signature)) ? 'verified' : 'not verified';
```

`$canonical` is the data I am verifying.
And this is the python code:

```
signature_str = rsa.sign(canonicalRequest.encode('utf8') , gt.privKey, 'SHA-256')
```

I'm guessing the signature block generated by python rsa contains maybe extra information or something but I haven't found any information regarding this.

Comment: So you have two strings. One verifies OK, the other doesn't. Let us exclude coding issues first. Could you verify visually both input strings to the verification? Are they identical? First question: Do they have the same length.

Comment: They are not identical because I'm using the PKCS1 mode which adds random padding to the signatures, so they are never the same.

Comment: Indeed, random padding to the text signed. Good you know. Do the signatures have the same length?

Comment: Just to clarify, what is happening is that if i sign the string in python and then verify it there, it verifies OK, when I send that signed string to my php code it doesn't verify there. I will check the length of the strings.

Comment: Yes, to exclude problems with the sending, in your test PHP code do `$signature = pasted python string`

Comment: How about `canonicalRequest.encode('utf8')`? Is that encoding applied identically at PHP side? Wouldn't you exclude that in your test first?

Comment: @Njord12 - could you post your public key and the signed message that isn't verifying?